# Check availability between dates using pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, availability

I'm working on a script for my school task using pascal. It is a rental  program.
I can't get anything in checking availability between starting date and end date.
I have both starting and end date in an array and also have starting and end date input by the user. The problem is how to set the availability to false when there's a crash in data I stored and data input. I'm using free pascal, and the date is a record. I tried by only using if and looping.

```
if(rdata[i].start_date.M<>rdata[i].ends_date.M)and(temprdata.start_date.M=data[i].start_date.M)and(temprdata.start_date.M=data[i].start_date.M)then
    begin
        if(temprdata.start_date.D>=rdata[i].start_date.D)then
            isavailable:=false;
        if
            if(temprdata.ends_date.D>=rdata[i].start_date.D)then
                isavailable:=false;
    end
    else
    if(rdata[i].start_date.M=rdata[i].ends_date.M)and(temprdata.start_date.M=data[i].start_date.M)and(temprdata.start_date.M=data[i].start_date.M)then
    begin
        if(temprdata.stat_date.D>=rdata[i].start_date.D)and(temprdata.stat_date.D<=rdata[i].ends_date.M)then
            isavailable:=false;
        if(temprdata.ends_date.D>=rdata[i].start_date.D)then
            isavailable:=false;
    end;
```

Comment: Why do you need an array to store a date? What type is  "rdata" and "temptdata"?

Comment: That's not your actual code, because it won't compile. (You have `if if` on lines 5 and 6, which is not valid syntax). If you want help with your code, you need to post *your actual code* and not something you made up while writing your question. Inventing or retyping code from memory means that we're not seeing the actual code with the problem you're describing, and you could introduce new problems (or hide the actual problem) in the new code. Please [edit] your question and provide your real code. While you're at it, you can include what `rdata[i].start_date.D` and the other types are, too.

Comment: Try to extract the date checks to a function isavailable(dt1,dt2:TDatetime):boolean;

Comment: Just a hint: instead of `if (temprdata.ends_date.D>=rdata[i].start_date.D) then isavailable:=false;` you can write simply `isavailable := (temprdata.ends_date.D < rdata[i].start_date.D)`